# Is there a way to reuse valgrind suppression files?

Tags: c++, valgrind, suppression

On my work I need to profile some software and got some suppression files that were recorded an unknown time ago. One of these files (logging.supp) is used to suppress logging errors.

I guess the logging and some other parts are changed between generation of the suppression file and my my profiling.

As far as I figure out valgrind uses the stack to identify if a leak should be suppressed.

Do I need to regenerate the suppression files or is there a way to change something in the files?

Example suppression entry:

```
{
<insert_a_suppression_name_here>
Memcheck:Leak
fun:_Znwj
fun:_ZN3tsd6common5types8SmartPtrINS0_7logging19LogSimpleDateFormatEEaSEPS4_
fun:_ZN3tsd6common7logging23LogDatePatternConverterC1ESt6vectorISsSaISsEE
fun:_ZN3tsd6common7logging16LogPatternParser15createConverterEcSt6vectorISsSaISsEE
fun:_ZN3tsd6common7logging16LogPatternParser17finalizeConverterEcSsiSsNS0_5types8SmartPtrINS1_17LogFormattingInfoEEERSt6vectorINS4_INS1_19LogPatternConverterEEESaIS9_EERS7_IS6_SaIS6_EE
fun:_ZN3tsd6common7logging16LogPatternParser5parseESsRSt6vectorINS0_5types8SmartPtrINS1_19LogPatternConverterEEESaIS7_EERS3_INS5_INS1_17LogFormattingInfoEEESaISC_EE
fun:_ZN3tsd6common7logging16PatternLogLayout15activateOptionsEv
fun:_ZN3tsd6common7logging16PatternLogLayoutC1ERKSs
fun:_ZN3tsd6common7logging14LoggingManager4initENS0_5types8SmartPtrINS1_23LogManagerConfigurationEEE
fun:_ZN3tsd6common7logging14LoggingManager4initERKSsS4_
fun:_ZN3tsd6common7logging14LoggingManager9getLoggerERKSs
fun:_ZN3tsd6common7logging6LoggerC1ERKSs
}
```

I found and liked this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14781867/2764334

Can I use the dots also to ignore some functions that are intermediate stack entries?

How are the function names generated? to me it looks like either _Znjw or _ZN3tsd is the name for main?

Can you help me where to find documentation to the above questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use the dots also to ignore some functions that are intermediate stack entries?

Yes.

> How are the function names generated?

They are mangled function names, as generated by the compiler; they contain the namespace and/or class scope, the function name, and the arguments. You can use `c++filt` to demangle them.

> to me it looks like either _Znjw or _ZN3tsd is the name for main?

`_Znjw` is `operator new(unsigned)`. `_ZN3tsd` is the prefix for things in `namespace tsd`.

> Can you help me where to find documentation to the above questions?

Valgrind suppression files are documented [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress). The GNU mangling format doesn't seem to be officially documented; use Google and take whatever you find with a pinch of salt (assuming you don't want to trawl through the compiler source to see how the names are generated).