# Valgrind complains reading from a file

Tags: io, fortran, valgrind, intel-fortran

When reading in a file, I usually check if `read` returns a negative `iostat` to see if I reached the end of the file.

If an intel compiler is used (2022 or 2023 versions of ifort and ifx), Valgrind complains that `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`. A minimal example would be:

```
program test_reading
    implicit none
    integer :: err_flag
    character(len = 5) :: input
    do
        read (*, *, iostat = err_flag) input
        if (err_flag < 0) exit ! EOF
    end do
end program
```

For any arbitrary input (here I tested it with the letter 'e') I get the following warning from Valgrind:

```
$ valgrind ./a.out
==630192== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==630192== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==630192== Using Valgrind-3.19.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==630192== Command: ./a.out
==630192==
e
==630192== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==630192==    at 0x41C8FD: for__characterize_LUB_buffer (in /path/to/a.out)
==630192==    by 0x41CB70: for__get_s (in /path/to/a.out)
==630192==    by 0x409495: for_read_seq_lis (in /path/to/a.out)
==630192==    by 0x40422D: MAIN__ (test2.f90:6)
==630192==    by 0x40419C: main (in /path/to/a.out)
==630192==
```

Why is that and what is the recommended way to read in a file until its end without any warnings from Valgrind?

I don't get this warning when I use gfortran. The optimization level does not have an influence.

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Which version?

Comment: And which OS and what inputs? I tried a few times with gfortran 12.2 on FreeBSD 13.2 amd64, Valgrind 3.22 and got no errors.

Comment: It seems to only happen when intel compilers (ifort or ifx) are used. The optimization level does not matter. Everything is tested under Rocky Linux 9 with the 2023 and 2022 releases of intel's oneAPI.

Comment: Consider changing the title to *"Valgrind complains reading from a file"*. You already seemed to have figured out that it is not related to using a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to Intel's implementation, and there is nothing you can do about it.
I remember similar Valgrind warnings resulting from `write` (or `print`) statements with `ifort`.

Consider using a Valgrind [suppression file](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.suppfiles) that ignores `for__characterize_LUB_buffer`.
See, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779512).

Comment: Thanks, do you have a guess what in there implementation causes this warning or what a `for__characterize_LUB_buffer` is?

Comment: No, but I would not worry about it. I'm assuming not all I/O statements are undefined behavior, whatever Valgrinds says. Unless the compiler has been very broken, and no one has noticed for generations. But if you're curious, then the Intel forum is the place to ask.