# Suppressing Valgrind warnings

Tags: valgrind

A colleague asked for help finding a tough-to-reproduce SIGSEGV in a program, so I'm running it through `valgrind` to look for any memory issues.

Unfortunately, I end up with this:

```
$ valgrind --track-origins=yes sim-server
==128768== 
==128768== More than 10000000 total errors detected.  I'm not reporting any more.
==128768== Final error counts will be inaccurate.  Go fix your program!
==128768== Rerun with --error-limit=no to disable this cutoff.  Note
==128768== that errors may occur in your program without prior warning from
==128768== Valgrind, because errors are no longer being displayed.
==128768==
```

Everything I can see comes from `libasound.2.0.0` or `libportaudio.so.2.0.0` and they all have the same warning:

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)
```

Example:

```
==130835== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==130835==    at 0x483865C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:306)
==130835==    by 0x483ADE7: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:834)
==130835==    by 0x48A209A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0)
==130835==    by 0x48A251F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0)
==130835==    by 0x48A5944: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0)
==130835==    by 0x4878EA6: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==130835==    by 0x4CECA2E: clone (clone.S:95)
==130835==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==130835==    at 0x4E626C0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
```

After installing `libportaudio2-dbysym` and `libasound2-dbgsym`, that becomes:

```
==135367== Thread 3:
==135367== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==135367==    at 0x483865C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:306)
==135367==    by 0x483ADE7: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:834)
==135367==    by 0x48A209A: PaAlsaStreamComponent_RegisterChannels (pa_linux_alsa.c:4003)
==135367==    by 0x48A251F: PaAlsaStream_SetUpBuffers (pa_linux_alsa.c:4114)
==135367==    by 0x48A5944: CallbackThreadFunc (pa_linux_alsa.c:4355)
==135367==    by 0x4878EA6: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==135367==    by 0x4CECA2E: clone (clone.S:95)
==135367==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==135367==    at 0x4E626C0: refine_back_time_and_size (pcm_ioplug.c:263)
```

I can see three logical explanations:

1. `libportaudio2`+`libasound2` are volatile and unusable dependencies that could crash at any moment

   - Since it seems to be widely used, I suspect this is not true.
2. My integration is to blame

   - All of the uninitialized stack values come from `libasound2`
   - I even get errors from inside of [`Pa_Initialize()`](https://www.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/initializing_portaudio.html) which is not a function that requires me to set anything up ahead of time.
   - It is still possible, but it wouldn't explain everything.
3. These messages can be ignored.

   - If I suppress portaudio/asound messages, I can focus on the things my program does wrong

How can I suppress `Conditional jump or move...` warnings originating from `libportaudio.so.2.0.0` in Valgrind?

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174468/is-it-possible-to-make-valgrind-ignore-certain-libraries), Valgrind's [documentation on supressing errors](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) and Valgrind's [documentation on writing suppression files](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.suppfiles), I've come up with this:

```
$ cat suppress.val
{
  ignore_asound_cond_jump_0
  Memcheck:Cond
  obj:*/libasound.so*
}
{
  ignore_pa
  Memcheck:Cond
  obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0
}
{
  ignore_pcm
  Memcheck:Cond
  obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so
}
{
  ignore_pa_8
  Memcheck:Value8
  obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0
}
{
  ignore_pulse
  Memcheck:Cond
  obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0.23.0
}
{
  ignore_pulsecommon
  Memcheck:Cond
  obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-14.2.so
}
{
  ignore_asound_ioctl
  Memcheck:Param
  ioctl(generic)
  fun:*
  obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
}
{
  ignore_pa_poll
  Memcheck:Param
  poll(timeout)
  fun:*
  obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0
}
{
  ignore_pa_malloc
  Memcheck:Param
  malloc
  fun:*
  obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0
}
$ valgrind --suppressions=suppress.val --track-origins=yes sim-sound
...
--135517-- 
--135517-- used_suppression:  27290 ignore_asound_cond_jump_0 suppress.val:2
--135517-- used_suppression:   7914 ignore_pulsecommon suppress.val:27
--135517-- used_suppression:  17884 ignore_pcm suppress.val:12
--135517-- used_suppression: 471481 ignore_pa suppress.val:7
--135517-- used_suppression:   3518 ignore_pulse suppress.val:22
--135517-- used_suppression:   1760 ignore_pa_8 suppress.val:17
--135517-- used_suppression:    606 ignore_pa_poll suppress.val:45
--135517-- used_suppression:     22 ignore_asound_ioctl suppress.val:38
==135517== 
==135517== ERROR SUMMARY: 60721 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 530475 from 1044)
```

That takes care of a lot of warnings, but the `malloc` one described above is not suppressed. It's not just malloc, others such as `memmove` from `vg_replace_strmem.c` is also an offender.  Those source files are not in my program and the stack allocation is not in my program. I've been playing with the `ignore_pa_malloc` receipie, but I'm really having trouble finding a rule set that will work.

Comment: Can you try the latest version of Valgrind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul Floyd has a suggestion about how to fix the problem.  That's probably better.  This answers how to suppress the error.  Note that if there is a problem with the portaudio integration, this could mask that problem.

The trick was to use a literal "`...`" line in the suppression file.

The following rule says:  Ignore "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" errors that occur within `libportaudio.so.2.0.0`.

```
{
  ignore_pa
  Memcheck:Cond
  obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0
}
```

However, the following occurs in `libc.so`:

```
==130835== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==130835==    at 0x483865C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:306)
==130835==    by 0x483ADE7: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:834)
==130835==    by 0x48A209A: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0)
==130835==    by 0x48A251F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0)
==130835==    by 0x48A5944: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0)
==130835==    by 0x4878EA6: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==130835==    by 0x4CECA2E: clone (clone.S:95)
```

The answer is a slight change to the recepie:

```
{
  ignore_pa
  Memcheck:Cond
  ...
  obj:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0
}
```

The `...` will cause us to ignore any `Memcheck:Cond` for any error with `libportaudio.so.2.0.0` in the stack.   This means errors in `libc.so` will not be raised if they came through `libportaudio.so.2.0.0`.

When reading documentation I thought `...` was just a truncation, but it's actually literal.  The Valgrind documentation says:

> A location line may also be simply "..." (three dots). This is a frame-level wildcard, which matches zero or more frames. Frame level wildcards are useful because they make it easy to ignore varying numbers of uninteresting frames in between frames of interest. That is often important when writing suppressions which are intended to be robust against variations in the amount of function inlining done by compilers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the realloc call is here

https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio/blob/master/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c

(the line numbers don't quite match)

```
        unsigned int bufferSize = self->numHostChannels * alsa_snd_pcm_format_size( self->nativeFormat, *numFrames );
        if( bufferSize > self->nonMmapBufferSize )
        {
            self->nonMmapBuffer = realloc( self->nonMmapBuffer, ( self->nonMmapBufferSize = bufferSize ) );
```

Either self->nonMmapBuffer or bufferSize is uninitialized.

According to https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-lib/blob/ed6b07084bfea4155bbc98bcf38508ab81bdd008/src/pcm/pcm_misc.c#L342

`snd_pcm_format_size` just returns a multiple of the `samples` argument (unless it is invalid - you would need to check with gdb if that is the case).

It's difficult to follow the code on github to get back to where Valgrind traced the origin.

If you can, try using Valgrind with gdb and the "mc xb" (or "monitor xb" for older gdb) to see which memory is uninitialize.

Comment: Nice find.  I'll run through these.  My program has a long stack of dependencies which starts at [`Gamma`](https://github.com/LancePutnam/Gamma) and then through `libportaudio`, so I might need to make PRs to a few projects to solve my crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
==130835== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==130835==    at 0x483865C: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:306)
```

That almost certainly means that `malloc` is being called with a size that is uninitialized. In my book that's a pretty serious error and likely to cause crashes.

Do you have any way to either get debuginfo packages for or debug builds of libportaudio and libasound?

Comment: I installed `libportaudio2-dbgsym` and `libasound2-dbgsym` and updated my question with the new output.